# 'GLIBC_2.25' not found on Ubuntu

Tags: glibc

Getting following error while compiling the visit (visualization tool)

```
pawar@pawar:/usr/local/visit/bin$ ./visit
./../current/linux-x86_64/bin/python: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by ./../current/linux-x86_64/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
```

What is the possible reason and how to sort it out ?

Comment: Which release of Ubuntu? Is the makefile specifying the version of glibc?

Comment: I suspect the issue is that it is supplying its own version of `libpython2.7` (in `./../current/linux-x86_64/lib/`) that was built with an incompatible (newer) version of `libc` than the one on your system

Comment: i am using 16.04 LTS